# Java - método con atributo tipo bool

Tags: java, booleano

Estoy teniendo errores en la definición de un método con input tipo *boolean*

Tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
public Athlete (String name, String surname, int birthYear, boolean medalist, char gender, String nationality){
        setName(name);
        setSurname(surname);
        setBirthYear(birthYear);
        isMedalist(medalist);
        setGender(gender);
        setNationality(nationality);
        setId();
    }

    public void setMedalist(boolean medalist){
        this.medalist = medalist;
    }

    public boolean isMedalist(){
        return this.medalist;
    }
```

Los test serían estos:

```
    @Test
    @Order(9)
    void testIsMedalist() {
        assertTrue(athlete.isMedalist());
    }

    @Test
    @Order(10)
    void testSetMedalist() {
        athlete.setMedalist(false);
        assertFalse(athlete.isMedalist());
    }
```

El error mostrado es `java cannot be applied to '(boolean )'`
Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Quiero que el setter sólo asigne su valor como parámetro.

Añado la clase Athlete completa:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Athlete {

    private int id;
    private static int nextId  = 0;
    private String name;                   // inicializar atributos
    private String surname;
    private int birthYear;
    private boolean medalist = false;
    private char gender;
    private String nationality;

   /* public Athlete (){
        this ("simone", "Biles", 1997, true, 'f', "USA");
    }*/

    // es Athlete o AthleteDefault?
    public Athlete (String name, String surname, int birthYear, boolean medalist, char gender, String nationality){
        setName(name);
        setSurname(surname);
        setBirthYear(birthYear);
        isMedalist(medalist);
        setGender(gender);
        setNationality(nationality);
        setId();
    }

    //ID
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId() {
        this.id = getNextId();
        incNextId();
    }

    public static int getNextId() {
        return nextId;
    }

    private void incNextId(){
        nextId++;
    }
```

ID: empieza en 0 y va sumando 1 por medio del parámetro netxId

Nombre: comprueba que no tenga mas de 30 caracteres.

```
    // NAME
    public void setName(String name){
        if (name.length()>30){
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's name cannot be longer than 30 characters");
        } else {
            this.name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);      // valido para nombres compuestos
        }
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
```

Apellido: comprueba que tenga menos de 50 caracteres. Lo cambia a mayúsculas.

```
    //SURNAME
    public void setSurname(String surname){
        if (surname.length()>50){
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's surname cannot be longer than 50 characters");
        }else {
            surname = surname.toUpperCase();                // apellido en mayusculas
            surname = surname.replace(' ','_');             // espacio entre palabras por '_'
        }
    }

    public String getSurname(){
        return surname;
    }
```

Año de nacimiento: comprueba que está dentro del rango.

```
    //BIRTHYEAR
    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear){
        if (1900 < birthYear && birthYear < 2010){
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's birth year must be in range [1900,2010]");
        }
    }

    public int getBirthYear(){
        return birthYear;
    }
```

Medallista: aquí está la duda. Sólo debe asignar el valor.

```
    // MEDALIST????
    public void setMedalist(boolean medalist){
        this.medalist = medalist;
    }

    public boolean isMedalist(){
        return this.medalist;
    }
```

Género: comprobaciones de valores válidos de entrada

```
    // GENDER
    public void setGender(char gender){
        if (this.gender != 'm' && this.gender != 'M' && this.gender != 'f' && this.gender != 'F'){
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's gender must be 'f', 'F', 'm' or 'M'");
        } else {
            this.gender = Character.toUpperCase(gender);
        }
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }
```

Nacionalidad: comprueba el valor de entrada de 3 caracteres

```
    // NATIONALITY
    public void setNationality(String nationality){
        if (this.nationality.length()>3){
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's nationality length must be always 3");
        } else {
            this.nationality = nationality.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    public String getNationality(){
        return this.nationality;
    }
```

Edad: la calcula entre el año de nacimiento y hoy (sólo el año)

```
    // AGE                                  // problema con la definicion de la fecha
    public int age;                         // asi bien definida?????
    public void setAge(int birthYear){
        age = birthYear - LocalDate.now().getYear();

        /* LocalDate birthyear = getBirthYear();         // hace falta 'this', mejor cambio de nombre de variable?
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now().getYear();
        Year age = Period.between(birthyear, now).getYears();*/
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
```

DorsaL: toma valores de nombre y apellido para componer un resultado final sólo si cumple los requisitos regex

```
    // DORSAL
    public String olimpicGames;
    public void setDorsal(String olimpicGames, String name, String surname){

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile ("^[A-Z].*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$.*");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(olimpicGames);
        if (mat.matches()){
            olimpicGames = olimpicGames + "_" + name.substring(0, 1) + surname.substring(0, surname.indexOf(" "));
        }else{
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's dorsal pattern is incorrect");
            olimpicGames = null;                  // esto es correcto? Cómo devuelve el valor NULL? quitar void?
        }
    }

    public String getDorsal(){
        return olimpicGames;
    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: pon el código completo de Athlete y corre el comando where javac si estás en windows o whereis javac si estás en linux para saber más de tu sistema

Comment: @RuslanLópez, estoy con IntelliJ. ejecutándolo me sale: ```error: method isMedalist in class Athlete cannot be applied to given types;
        isMedalist(medalist);``` Además, ```reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length```

Comment: pon el código completo de Athlete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno tu error es tan obvio que el compilador mismo lo marcó.

El método `isMedalist` no recibe parámetros porque solo recupera el estado interno.

Por eso tu error dice que no se puede aplicar porque la lista de argumentos difiere en longitud.

donde está eso? En el constructor!

```
isMedalist(medalist);
```

debería de ser

```
setMedalist(medalist);
```